# Convergence of a Maclaurin series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Consider a function $$f(x)=\frac{4x^4}{x^2+6}.$$
Find its Maclaurin series and for what values of $x$ it converges?

My effort: I start with
$$\frac{4x^4}{x^2+6}=\frac{2x^4}{3}\bigg(1+\frac{x^2}{6}\bigg)^{-1}$$ $$=\frac{2x^4}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\bigg(\frac{x^2}{6}\bigg)^n.$$
Above series converges only if $x^2<6$ (by Leibniz rule). Am I correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. You identified part of the expression as the sum of a geometric series, obtained the development, and the interval on which the development is valid. Although this is debatable, since the mclaurin series is defined as $\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$, some might expect that you present you result in that form, i.e., something like
$$
f(x)= \sum_{n\ge 0} \dfrac{2 (-1)^n}{3 \cdot 6^n} x^{2n+4}.
$$